# Laundry - sort socks

Tags: c#, .net

This is very artificial problem
Each sock has exactly 1 match. 
Can only take one random sock out of the Laundry basket.
Can only compare to the last random sock. 
If it matches you put the match aside. 
It is like you have a stack of socks and you can only match on the top sock. 
So if the match is down the sock pile you are not going to find a match. 
But you don't even get to look down the sock pile to even know if the match is in the sock pile. You only get to match to the top sock. 
You will *eventually* need to put the sock pile back in the Laundry basket. 
You can throw the unmatched socks back in the Landry basket at any time but they come out random

On CS there is a guy telling me he has a better algorithm but he cheats and searches the sock pile for a match down the pile.

```
public static void MatchSocks()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<int> Laundry = new List<int>();
    List<int> Matched = new List<int>();
    List<int> Unmatched = new List<int>();
    int? LastUnmatched = null;
    int Sock;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Laundry.Add(i);
        Laundry.Add(i);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        count++;
        if(Laundry.Count == 0)
        {
            if (Unmatched.Count == 0)
                break;
            Laundry = new List<int>(Unmatched);
            Unmatched.Clear();
            LastUnmatched = null;
        }
        Sock = Laundry.ElementAt(rand.Next(Laundry.Count));
        Laundry.Remove(Sock);
        if (LastUnmatched == null)
        {
            Unmatched.Add(Sock);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Sock == LastUnmatched)
            {
                Matched.Add(Sock);
                Unmatched.Remove(Sock);
            }
            else
            {
                Unmatched.Add(Sock);
            }
        }
        LastUnmatched = Sock;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(count);
}
```

Comment: If it's possible to clear up your explanation with an example that would be very helpful - i found it a little vague and couldn't quite conceptualise it. if a sock doesn't match, are you forced to throw it out?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon "Each sock has exactly 1 match"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using some poor methods when there are better options available to the data types you've picked.

A huge bottleneck is hidden in those 2 lines:

> ```
> Sock = Laundry.ElementAt(rand.Next(Laundry.Count));
> Laundry.Remove(Sock);
> ```

Let's see why

### General vs specific methods

`ElementAt` is an extension method of the type `IEnumerable<T>`, the `List<T>` is inheriting `IEnumerable<T>` but guess what, so are most of the collections in C#. That means when you write a method that is applicable to so many types, you need to make it as generic/general as possible while still maintaining reasonable performance, but of course using a concrete implementation of that method for said collection would be faster. You can do that because you are 100% sure that the optimizations will always be valid.

So the first thing is to replace the `ElementAt()` with normal indexer.

### `RemoveAt()` vs `Remove()`

In most cases `Remove()` would be a O(n) operation where `RemoveAt()` would be O(1) operation. The first uses the latter internally so it's always better to use this method when you know what index you want to remove, guess what, you already know what index you're removing:

```
int index = rand.Next(Laundry.Count);
Sock = Laundry[index];
Laundry.RemoveAt(index);
```

---

Besides that you're never utilizing the collection `Matched`. You're just wasting time adding stuff into it without ever touching them.

---

Adding those changes made the code about 2.5 times faster. On average from 45ms  to about 17ms per run.

Comment: Nice, I want Matched to verify it has the correct number of items.

Comment: That makes sense, but you can remove it when you're testing the speed of the algorithm. Aside from that it looks pretty clean :)

Comment: This is not entirely true with `IEnumerable`, many extensions are aware of the `IList` interface and try to use this one instead of iterating the entire collection, so does the [`ElementAt(OrDefault)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,76a0d6af544d8d2b)

Comment: @t3chb0t I know that in the `Count` extension method, if the parameter is of type `ICollection` it wont iterate the whole collection, but to check the type you still need to perform some extra operations right? While you're right it wont be as slow as if it was on a pure Enumerable, but it should still be slightly slower than direct indexing. Without any clear benefit in this specific case.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's slower due to the dynamic casting with `as`.

Comment: Just FYI - `RemoveAt` is also `O(n)`because it has to shift the other members down to fill the gap created.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is whether you want to compare the speed of the *algorithms* (in terms of abstract operations) or the speed of the *implementations* (on a specific hardware implementation). For the former, it doesn't matter whether you use `Remove` or `RemoveAt`. Depending of course on the definition of your abstract machine and what operations it provides.

-To improve the algorithm you should remember which socks you already drew out and what the chances are to find a pair in the remaining socks. Maximize this probability in each step. For example, if lots of pairs remain in the basket, you ahould continue to draw. But if there are only singles left, you should put all socks back in.-

To prevent you from accidental cheating you should define a class `LaundryBasket` that only provides two operations: `DrawRandomSock` and `PutBackAll`. The laundry should also be the only point in the code that knows about the randomness.

To get reproducible test results, you should initialize the `Random` with a fixed seed, so you can trace exactly what the algorithm is doing and why.

Comment: You don't get to remember.  You only get to match top sock.

Comment: Too bad. I thought I could do that by drawing an analogy to the real world, and because the rules only talked about the laundry basket, not so much of the socks drawn out of it.

Comment: "But you don't even get to look down the sock pile to even know if the match is in the sock pile."

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same algorithm as yours but by shuffling the unmatched pile at the start of each iteration, you can remove the costly calls to `Remove` items from the lists.

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rand.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}

public static void MatchSocks()
{
    List<int> matched = new List<int>();
    List<int> unmatched = new List<int>();
    int? lastSock;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        unmatched.Add(i);
        unmatched.Add(i);
    }
    while (unmatched.Count > 0)
    {
        var unmatchedThisTime = new List<int>(unmatched.Count);
        Shuffle(unmatched);
        lastSock = unmatched[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < unmatched.Count; i++) 
        {
            var sock = unmatched[i];
            if (lastSock.HasValue) 
            {
                if (lastSock.Value == sock) 
                {
                    matched.Add(sock);
                    lastSock = null;
                    continue;
                }
                unmatchedThisTime.Add(lastSock.Value);
            }
            lastSock = sock;
        }
        if (lastSock.HasValue)
        {
            unmatchedThisTime.Add(lastSock.Value);
        }
        unmatched = unmatchedThisTime;
    }
}
```

This takes the average run time from ~45ms to ~10ms on my machine (YMMV).

I also think it's a more intuitive solution:

1. Shuffle the remaining socks to be paired
2. Draw one sock at a time comparing to the previously drawn sock
3. If the socks match, put them in the matched pile
4. Otherwise, add the previously drawn sock to the unmatched pile
5. Compare all socks this way
6. Start again with the unmatched pile

That is, as long as I have understood your problem statement correctly.

Comment: I agree this is more efficient but you are literally supposed to pick from the laundry basket one at a time.

Comment: @Paparazzi - Picking up a sock one at a time from a shuffled pile is the same as rummaging around in an ordered pile each time IMO

Comment: Result may be the same but the action is not the same